# So many reviews for Late Answers. Is this normal or a bug?

Tags: discussion

Just now I have seen so many pending reviews under **Late Answers**. I have never seen so many in my entire time at SO. Is this normal or any bug in the system? I personally think 1.5k is not normal for **Late Answers**. I usually see around 10 and more than 10 very rarely. [image]

Comment: Because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue)

Comment: @bluefeet Well, then one more badge in my bag coming soon :)

Comment: @bluefeet maybe that could be an answer? Being as there have already been two duplicate questions on the topic posted?

Comment: @TinyGiant Stepping away from my keyboard for a bit, so feel free to post one.

Comment: And would you look at that.  It's already down to only 700 or so.

Comment: Down to the low 300's.

Comment: And it's been zeroed out! Good work, SO.

Comment: Looks like there's still a residual lump of several hundred questions from this in the VLQ queue that still needs burned down.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> [[image]
> <sub>The image leads to the reason</sub>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue)

There, I posted one @bluefeet.

All joking aside, this is because [@durron597's MSE request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue) to "raise the bar for reputation for late answers to enter the review queue" has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). This means that there will (most likely) be a larger number in that queue <s>from this point forth (or until they change their mind).</s> for an hour or so.

Comment: I see, so previously only users with less than 10 rep who posted late would have their posts in the queue. Now we may see users who have up to 50, and in the future, 100. 

Great, I always thought the LA queue could handle more volume.

Comment: @Trobbins that seems to be the consensus everywhere but ServerFault :)